# I'm facing issue with highmaps , it's related to displaying the passed data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have checked various examples, but coudn't find one with this case.
My data will be in this format

```
{
"INDIA": {
    "value": 1228,
    "sumothervalue": 962,
    "total": 2190
},
"CHINA": {
    "value": 45,
    "sumothervalue": 0,
    "total": 45
},
"RUSSIA": {
    "value": 748,
    "sumothervalue": 0,
    "total": 748
},
"US": {
    "value": 964,
    "sumothervalue": 100,
    "total": 1064
 }
}
```

Assuming the country code are in suitable format, how can I show the value in the map as in the image below

[image]

Comment: What does your `tooltip.formatter` code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tooltip and print the required data.

```
 tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '',
            pointFormat: 'Name: {point.name} <br> Some Data: {point.somedata} <br> Value: {point.value}'
        }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Prepare demo data
    var data = [
        {
            "hc-key": "in",
            "somedata":"Random Data 28",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "us",
            "somedata":"Random Data 32",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "ru",
            "somedata":"Random Data 55",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "bd",
            "somedata":"Random Data 88",
            "value": 3
        }
    ];

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

        title : {
            text : 'Highmaps'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '',
            pointFormat: 'Name: {point.name} <br> Some Data: {point.somedata} <br> Value: {point.value}'
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.value}'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is working for me, it's just that the code snippet that you gave is not running. Can you check that before I accept your answer?

Comment: @Khacho - What do you see after running it ? As its working fine for me.

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 66,
  "colno": 22
}